# Qgis network prepare road graph

Tags: qgis, network, road, graph

I have been working on finding shortest path between two buildings. For that purpose i have created kml files of various streets, converted them into shape files and then merged all of them together.
Now, when i try to use road graph plugin, it says that the plugin is not configured. I think that perhaps similar to arcGIS i might be required to prepare network dataset before using the plugin.
Can anyone help me with this problem?